# Catch exception but do retry with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

By default sidekiq will retry any jobs that throw an exception. That is fine. However, I want to be able to catch that exception so that my exception handler doesn't get notified, and then retry the job. How do I accomplish this in react?

So my code looks like this:

```
def perform
  ...
rescue ExcClass => ex
  # log
end
```

But I want to actually retry that job.

Answer (score 5):

Configure your error service client to ignore ExcClass.  Sidekiq will retry, you don't get error reports.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm following your question correctly, it sounds like you may want a custom error handler to do what you want:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.error_handlers << Proc.new {|exception,context_hash| MyErrorService.notify(exception,context_hash) }
end
```

By default, Sidekiq will continue to retry your jobs automatically.

Does this answer your question? It's slightly confusing. [Here are the docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling) from which I pulled the above information.