# Sidekiq/Rails: How to catch exception AND retry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have sidekiq jobs running Selenium. If the job crashes, I need to

1. catch the exception to shut down the selenium driver (otherwise all coming jobs will crash as well),
2. notify error handler (Sentry)
3. Have sidekiq try again

Today I can catch and notify, but by catching the exception Sidekiq will not retry the job.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123960/catch-exception-but-do-retry-with-sidekiq) but a) it got no answer and b) that user did not want to notify its error handling service.

How do I get Sidekiq to retry the job even though I catch the exception?

Answer (score 5):

How about re-raising exception? It would be something like this:

```
def perform
  # perform_code
rescue ErrorClass => error
  # handle error
  raise error
end
```

This way, sidekiq is gonna repeat this task (because it raises an error), but the handling code will also be executed.

Comment: In this case I'd get the same error twice on sentry, correct? If I raise the error myself, can I still pass extra data to sentry? I normally do it on the error handling.